# 2 factor authentication using a USB drive

Tags: usb, security, authentication

I want to set up 2 factor authentication using a usb stick/drive. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and it seems that `libpam` and `pamusb` no longer work for this version.

I don't want to use google authenticator, I don't want to use a mobile phone, I want to use a USB stick.

Comment: That an interesting question, i would love to see this answered :)

Comment: you and me both  lol ;0)

Comment: Very good question indeed – does [`pamu2fcfg`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/pamu2fcfg) help?

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:njj/pamusb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pamusb-tools libpam-usb

Comment: this managed to install libpam and pamusb if anyone ever needs to do this. As for the usb stick im still having problems, my ubuntu image running in virtual box cant detect the usb drive, anyone know how to resolve this? Thanks